# php append non existing element to string

Tags: php, string, variables, undefined

Is there a way to prevent using if to check if an element exists before append ing itto a string, so it does not cause an error?

e.g.

```
$output = "";
if($data['element'])
{
   $output .= $data['element'];
}
```

in Javascript I can use:

```
var output = "";
output += data['element'] || '';
```

Comment: Null Coalescence Operator: `$output .= $data['element'] ?? null`;

Comment: @MarkBaker Indeed, but only supported in php 7 ^

Comment: @MarkBaker I am using php 7. So this is exactly what I needed. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always use the Ternary Operator  ?:

```
$output .= (isset($data['element'])) ? $data['element'] : '';
```

From the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

> The expression (expr1) ? (expr2) : (expr3) evaluates to expr2 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 if expr1 evaluates to FALSE.
>
> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

use isset to check it.

```
$output = "";
if(isset($data['element']))
{
   $output .= $data['element'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP Ternary Operator like this:

```
(isset($data['element'])) ? $output=$data['element'] : $output="";
```